# JavaScript Background Perspective Library

Tags: javascript, animation

I remember seeing this on Ajaxian and a couple other sites but I never bookmarked it, now i can't find it again. It's a javascript library that allows you to move your mouse over an image that's been chopped into layers and change perspective. Any links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about parallax scrolling?

http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html